# Magento : Soap api not working

Tags: php, api, magento, soap

Hi i am using magento vesion 1. 9
and i am trying to call magento soap apiv2 using php.

i use the following code.

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://domain/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1');
$sessionId = $proxy->login((object)array('username' => 'user', 'apiKey' => 'password'));
$product=$proxy->catalogProductInfo((object)array('sessionId' => $sessionId->result, 'productId' => '27'));
```

i get the session id (i testes it by printing the id)
but when i make a soap call

```
$product=$proxy->catalogProductInfo((object)array('sessionId' => $sessionId->result, 'productId' => '27'));
```

the browser showing "Server error"

api user having full permission in the back end.
but still it is not working. please some one help me to find the solution.

Comment: If you get "server error", I'd suggest that you check out your Magento logs, and your server logs :)

Comment: Did you solve the issue? @Arul James

Comment: I want to get category tree, i am using soap v2, my code: https://justpaste.it/7tgj1 and saved as bala.php in my root folder then try with 192.168.1.65/anusthana/bala.php output -> https://snag.gy/ywQMgY.jpg how can i solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems a bit bloated. Try this:

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://domain/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1');
$sessionId = $proxy->login("username", "password");
$product = $proxy->catalogProductInfo($sessionId, '27');
print_r($product); // just to see the output
```

If you want to re-use the code I'd suggest the following anyway:

```
$host = "domain.ext"; // replace with your domain name
$username = "username"; // replace with your soap user
$password = "password"; // replace with your user's password
$productId = "27";

$proxy = new SoapClient("http://".$host."/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1");
$sessionId = $proxy->login($username, $password);
$product = $proxy->catalogProductInfo($sessionId, $productId);

print_r($product); // just to see the output
```

A nice hint if you want to see what other functions are available:

```
$functions = $proxy->__getFunctions ();
var_dump($functions);
```

Hope it helps :)

Regards

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Client] Error cannot find parameter in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_test/api_test.php:6 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_test/api_test.php(6): SoapClient->__call('login', Array) #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_test/api_test.php(6): SoapClient->login('divum', 'divum123') #2 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_test/api_test.php on line 6

Comment: This is what i am getting

Comment: Hmm... strange, I can connect to my Magento 1.9 shop with this code without problems. What version of php have you currently installed? Are you using exactly the code I posted or did you modify it in anyway (apart from host, username and password, obviously)

Comment: the problem in in my magento pack. same code working in fresh install

Comment: Does your initially posted code work for you after the fresh installation? Because it didn't with my own magento 1.9 eshop. If that's also your case, please consider marking my answer as valid.

Comment: Ok, nice. Strange enough, I get this error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string. But if its working for you, not a problem :D Cheers

Comment: you need to enable wsdl from the configuration to use this code. Go to System->configuration->Magento Core API-> and enable "WS-I Compliance"

Comment: @EduardoLópez I want to get category tree, i am using soap v2, my code: https://justpaste.it/7tgj1 and saved as bala.php in my root folder then try with 192.168.1.65/anusthana/bala.php output -> https://snag.gy/ywQMgY.jpg how can i solve the issue?